# Why is object reference destroyed prematurely?

Tags: vba, macos, class, office365

I have created a simple VBA class with a parameterized constructor. The class has the VB_PredeclaredID=True. This development is being done on a Mac in Office 365. The code is below. (The code is not bulletproof. I created this simple example to show the problem that showed up in a more complex class.) When the 5th line of the Make procedure is executed, the Class_Terminate handler is invoked for the object created in the 2nd line, i.e., the one controlling the "with" block. Class_Terminate crashes on exit with an overflow error. (On my more complex example, the error is "with without end.") I've planted debug so I know the Birthday property is never called in line 5. Can someone explain to me what in my code is causing the system to want to destroy the object reference when it is still in use, and how I can work around it? Thanks.

```
Sub TestClass()
    Dim cl As CTest
    Set cl = CTest.Make(DateValue("12/6/1946"))
    Debug.Print "TestClass", IIf(Not cl Is Nothing, cl.Birthday, "Nothing")
End Sub

Private m_birthday As Date
Private m_otherdata As Variant

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Debug.Print "Enter Initialize"
    If Me Is CTest Then
        m_birthday = DateValue("1/1/1800")
    Else
        m_birthday = Now()
    End If
    Debug.Print "Exit Initialize", m_birthday
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
End Sub

Public Function Make(varparam As Variant) As CTest
  If Me Is CTest Then
      With New CTest
          Select Case VarType(varparam)
              Case vbDate:
                  .Birthday = varparam
              Case vbObject:
                  .Birthday = varparam.Birthday
          End Select
          Set Make = .Self
      End With
  ElseIf varparam Is Nothing Then
      With New CTest
          .Birthday = Me.Birthday
          If (VarType(Me.OtherData)) = vbObject Then
            Set .OtherData = Me.OtherData
          Else
            .OtherData = Me.OtherData
          End If
          Set Make = .Self
      End With
  Else
    Set Make = Nothing
  End If
End Function

Public Property Get Self() As CTest
    Set Self = Me
End Property

Public Property Get Birthday() As Date
    Birthday = m_birthday
End Property

Public Property Let Birthday(val As Date)
    m_birthday = val
End Property

Public Property Get OtherData() As Variant
    OtherData = m_otherdata
End Property

Public Property Let OtherData(val As Variant)
    m_otherdata = val
End Property

Public Property Set OtherData(val As Variant)
    Set m_otherdata = val
End Property
```

Comment: Object lifetime issues can't be diagnosed without seeing the code that's using the class... This *looks* something like a pattern derived from what I have published.. I see code that looks like it's testing for invokes from the default instance.. is that the case? The class has a predeclared ID?

Comment: Consider `If Not Me Is CTest Then Err.Raise 5` to bail out immediately with an error if `Make` isn't invoked from the default instance - returning `Nothing` is just delaying the failure.

Comment: *the error is "with without end."* - that's a compile-time error, it can't crash on exit... it doesn't even run. And you haven't included the `Terminate` handler. I really, really want to help here, but you need to [edit] your post with the actual code that's blowing up, or at least a [mcve] that reproduces the problem... this isn't it.

Answer (score 0):

> *I created this simple example to show the problem that showed up in a more complex class*

What's missing is code that consumes the class, and the code that actually reproduces the problem, but I wrote a lot of articles on this subject, so let's dig anyway.

> ```
> Private Sub Class_Initialize()
>     Debug.Print "Enter Initialize"
>     If Me Is CTest Then
>         m_birthday = DateValue("1/1/1800")
>     Else
>         m_birthday = Now()
>     End If
>     Debug.Print "Exit Initialize", m_birthday
> End Sub
> ```

A useful piece of information that you're not outputting, is whether the initializing instance is the default instance. Consider:

```
Debug.Print "Initializing " & TypeName(Me) & IIf(Me Is CTest, " (default instance)", vbNullString)
```

One problem is this:

> ```
>     If Me Is CTest Then
>         m_birthday = DateValue("1/1/1800") '<~
>     Else
>         m_birthday = Now()
>     End If
> ```

If the current instance is the class' default instance, the internal state is useless. Keeping the default instance *stateless* is key, in fact: `m_birthday` is an implementation detail as far as the class' default interface (`CTest`) is concerned. This would be a better guard clause:

```
    If Me Is CTest Then Exit Sub
    m_birthday = Now()
```

No more nesting, `m_birthday` is only assigned on a non-default instance, and the intent of keeping the default instance stateless is much more explicitly expressed.

Now, if you type this in the *immediate pane*:

```
Set a = New CTest
```

You'll get this output:

```
Initializing CTest (default instance)
Initializing CTest
```

You're missing this trace:

> ```
> Private Sub Class_Terminate()
>     Debug.Print "Terminating " & TypeName(Me) & IIf(Me Is CTest, " (default instance)", vbNullString)
> End Sub
> ```

In the `Make` factory method, you actually want an even stronger bail-out:

> ```
> Public Function Make(varparam As Variant) As CTest
>   If Me Is CTest Then
>     '...
> ```

Consider:

```
Public Function Make(varparam As Variant) As CTest
    If Not Me Is CTest Then Err.Raise 5, TypeName(Me), "Member call is only valid from default/predeclared instance."
```

And that removes a branch in the conditional path. It also makes me wonder about this:

> ```
>   ElseIf varparam Is Nothing Then
> ```

That condition gets evaluated when `Me Is CTest` is `False`, i.e. when the factory method is invoked from a user instance... and that should not be allowed to happen.

This is another problem:

```
      Select Case VarType(varparam)
          Case vbDate:
              .Birthday = varparam
          Case vbObject:
              .Birthday = varparam.Birthday
```

`vbObject` means `varparam` is an `Object` reference - not that it's a `CTest` object: because we're working with a `Variant`, the member call is late-bound, so if the object doesn't have a `Birthday` member, we have run-time error 438 raised here. We can keep the member call late-bound but still validate the type:

```
Case vbObject:
    If TypeOf varparam Is CTest Then .Birthday = varparam.Birthday
```

Or you can get compile-time validation by introducing a variable:

```
Case vbObject:
    Dim typedParam As CTest
    If TypeOf varparam Is CTest Then 
        Set typedParam = varparam
        .Birthday = typedParam.Birthday '<~ early-bound member call now
    End If
```

This not only helps the compiler pick up typos (even `Option Explicit` can't save you from a typo in a late-bound call), it also helps static code analysis tooling like [Rubberduck](http://www.github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck), that now "see" the member call: if the member is renamed, refactoring tools can now update this call site - that's not easily possible with late-bound code.

> ```
> Public Property Get Self() As CTest
>     Set Self = Me
> End Property
> ```

That's syntax sugar that works nicely when there's an explicit interface involved, to cleanly separate the stateless `CTest` default instance from the `ICTest` explicit client interface (which could include a `Property Get` for the birthday, but no `Let` accessor).

Better syntax sugar that doesn't affect your classes' public interfaces and dramatically cleans up the locals toolwindow in class modules, is shoving the instance state into a `Private Type`:

```
Private Type TState
    Birthday As Date
    OtherData As Variant '<~ note: this breaks strong-typing and gets you back into late-bound land.
End Type
Private this As TState
```

This `Private this` instance (module-level) variable replaces all `m_`-prefixed variables, and now the `Birthday` property reads like this:

```
Public Property Get Birthday() As Date
    Birthday = this.Birthday
End Property

Public Property Let Birthday(ByVal val As Date)
    this.Birthday = val
End Property
```

...

So, the only convoluted piece of code that looks suspect, is the `Make` function, which is responsible for too many things.

Write a separate private function that works off a `Date`, another that works off a `CTest` object, and conditionally invoke the appropriate one from `Make`.

With functions that do fewer things, fewer things can go wrong.

Guard your methods - if a method involves instance state, prohibit invoking it from the default/predeclared instance. If a method is supposed to be invoked from the default instance, prohibit calling it from other instances.

See [this article](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2016/01/11/oop-in-vba-immutability-the-factory-pattern/) for a refresher on the pattern, and [this one](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2020/04/22/secure-adodb/) to see it in action with real code.

Comment: You are correct: I borrowed heavily from your work of several years ago in designing factory method. I added to the post the driver I used for testing. As I said in the original post, the code I was posting was not bullet proof. I was putting down the minimum I needed to reproduce an error. The original error was in fact "object variable or with block variable not set."

Comment: I added some of the tracing code you recommended. I executed the driver without any breakpoints, and the code ran fine. I went back to stepping through, and the code crashed with a premature invocation of Terminate. So I don't know if there really is a problem in the code and if there is it may be effectively non-reproducible.

Comment: @user103011 I copied your code verbatim into a `CTest` class in a new VBA project, and could not work out a way to use the class and reproduce the problem (no crash, no premature termination, nothing - then again, we don't know what *your* repro code looks like, because you haven't posted it). What I *could* see, was a factory method trying to also be a copy constructor, and a need to de-tangle these two responsibilities into their own separate scopes. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have to doff my cap to @MathieuGuindon and the other chaps and chapesses at Rubberduck as my understanding of VBA has progressed immensely through reading the Rubberduck blogs.

I too have been through some interesting times using the PredeclaredId and therfore offer some of my thoughts on how the OP code should be constructed.  As I am still developing my understanding of OOP in VBA folks should feel free to shoot me down in flames if I am wrong or misunderstanding things.

There are two things that I have developed from ideas presented in the rubberduck blogs.

**This**

I differentiate 'this' into p,s,b and u representing Type definitions of Properties, State,BaseInstance and Using.

**Self**

I take the construction of a Class instance a step further and pass the Make parameters to the Self method call.  In this way the parameters can be used to set up private members of the new instance without the need for public properties.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestCTest()

    Dim myCTest As CTest

    ' no errors
    Set myCTest = CTest.Make(DateValue("4/6/2020"))
    Debug.Print myCTest.Birthday

    On Error Resume Next
    ' Gives "CTest: Expecting Variant/Date or Variant/CTest: Found String"
    Set myCTest = CTest.Make("4/6/2020")
    Debug.Print Err.Description

    On Error GoTo 0
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim myCtest2 As CTest
    'Gives "CTest: Make should only be used with the PredeclaredId"
    Set myCtest2 = myCTest.Make(DateValue("4/6/2020"))
    Debug.Print Err.Description

    On Error GoTo 0
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Gives "New is not permitted outside of the Make Method" error
    Dim myCtest3 As CTest
    Set myCtest3 = New CTest
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

**Class CTest**

```
Option Explicit
'@PredeclaredId

' Variables used as the private repositories for public properties are located here
Private Type Properties

    Birthday                As Date
    OtherData               As Variant ' OP may have a specific type in mind
    ' NewIsAllowed appears in every instance but we will only ever use
    ' the value in the predeclared Id to toggle if new is or is not allowed
    ' via the AllowNew property
    NewIsAllowed            As Boolean

End Type

Private p As Properties

' If any were present the State type would be used for variables representing
' the state of the instance but which are not intended to be made public through Properties
' Private Type State
'   StateVar1 as Typename
' End Type
'
' Private s As State
'
' Used only for PredeclaredId to allow boilerplate code to be written
Private Type BaseInstance

    PredeclaredId           As CTest

End Type

Private b As BaseInstance

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    ' This method runs the **first** time the **PredecalredID** is used in an expression
    ' and for every subsequent use of New.  Therefore managing what happens for the PredeclaredId
    ' vs instances can become a bit Eulerish.

    ' Declaring b.predeclaredId allows us to boilerplate code elsewhere
    ' as it means that the only places that the actual class name is used
    ' is here ,the Type declaration above and other method declarations.
    Set b.PredeclaredId = CTest

    ' The code to exit on the first use of the PredeclaredID in an expression
    If Me Is b.PredeclaredId Then Exit Sub

    ' Trap the use of New when not used by the Make Function
    ' the code below means that bad code will be detected at testing time
    If Not AllowNew Then

        Err.Raise 445 + vbObjectError, TypeName(Me), TypeName(Me) & ": New is not permitted outside of the Make method"

    End If

End Sub

Public Function Make(ByVal varparam As Variant) As CTest
    ' From the OP code we are expecting varparam to be either
    ' a Date , a CTest object or nothing
    If InStr("Date,CTest,Empty,Null,Nothing", TypeName(varparam)) = 0 Then

       Err.Raise 13 + vbObjectError, TypeName(Me), TypeName(Me) & ": Expecting Variant/Date or Variant/CTest: Found " & TypeName(varparam)

    End If


    ' In the OP code it is not clear if the OP has
    ' restricted the use of the Make function to CTest.Make or 
    ' allows the use of <instance>.Make.
    ' Both uses are legal as Make is a public method but
    ' in the spirit of declaring a PredecalredId it is
    ' preferable to restrict the use of Make to CTest.Make
    ' Thus the code below detects the use of Make by an instance.
    If Not Me Is b.PredeclaredId Then

        Err.Raise 445 + vbObjectError, TypeName(Me), TypeName(Me) & ": Make should only be used with the PredeclaredId"

    End If

    ' Instruct the PredeclaredId that New is allowed
    AllowNew = True

    With New CTest

        Set Make = .Self(varparam)

    End With

    ' Instruct the PredeclaredId to disallow the use of new
    AllowNew = False

End Function

Public Function Self(ByVal varparam As Variant) As CTest

    ' This code is inside the new instance that is being constructed.
    ' Therefore there is free access to the private variables of the
    ' instance 'under construction'



    ' Its a little difficult to untangle the OP logic for what constitutes
    ' the birthday so the Case statement below may well be incorrect

    Select Case TypeName(varparam)

        Case "Empty", "Null", "Nothing"

            ' The Me in the OP code occurs in the Make function and
            ' consequently refers to the instance of which Make was called.
            ' IF make was used as discussed above this implies that Me is b.PredecalredId
            ' only if the OP has adhered to CTest.Make
            ' If this is the case????
            p.Birthday = DateValue("1/1/1800")

            ' The OP assigns otherdata in the case of nothing
            ' using Me.Otherdata.  The Me will now refer to the
            ' the instance under construction so it is likely that a second
            ' parameter will be required for the Make function
                       '

        Case "Date"

            p.Birthday = CDate(varparam)

        Case "CTest"

            Dim myCTest As CTest
            Set myCTest = varparam
            p.Birthday = myCTest.Birthday

        Case Else

            Err.Raise 13 + vbObjectError, TypeName(Me), TypeName(Me) & ": Expecting Variant/Date or Variant/CTest: Found " & TypeName(varparam)

    End Select

    Set Self = Me

End Function

' The alternative to the AllowNew property is to have a public AllowNew field.
' but as the code below is bolerplate and can be copied to new classes without issue
' I'm happy to use the code below.

' Due to the differentiation of p,s,b
' we have an easily identifiable warning to check if we
' see anything but the p. prefix in Property declarations.
Public Property Get AllowNew() As Boolean

    If Me Is b.PredeclaredId Then
        AllowNew = p.NewIsAllowed
    Else
        AllowNew = b.PredeclaredId.AllowNew
    End If

End Property

Public Property Let AllowNew(ByVal Value As Boolean)

    If Me Is b.PredeclaredId Then
        p.NewIsAllowed = Value
    Else
        b.PredeclaredId.AllowNew = Value
    End If

End Property

Public Property Get Birthday() As Date
    Birthday = p.Birthday
End Property

Public Property Let Birthday(ByVal val As Date)
    p.Birthday = val
End Property

Public Property Get OtherData() As Variant
    OtherData = p.OtherData
End Property

Public Property Let OtherData(ByVal val As Variant)
    p.OtherData = val
End Property

Public Property Set OtherData(ByVal val As Variant)
    Set p.OtherData = val
End Property
```

Comment: A `Public Property Get Self()` that returns `Me` is simple and straightforward. A side-effecting function named `Self` that takes parameters and returns `Me` is confusing, and the `AllowNew` property is making the default instance stateful - that toggle is effectively global state, and I would vehemently oppose it in a design brainstorm discussion with my rubber ducky. There is no "next step" with the pattern I proposed, and taking shortcuts is making things *much* harder to debug & follow. Now execution breaks and you have no idea what instance you're in! Define. Explicit. Interfaces. ;-)